# jQuery: How do I chain .live() with .ajaxForm()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I pull in via XHR, so it isn't ready when the DOM is initially rendered. Currently I use something like:

```
jQuery("[name='myform']").ajaxForm({ /* code here */ });
```

and it works fine on a stand alone app. The app I'm embedding it in is huge, and I need to be able to bind ajaxForm to myform before myform is available to the DOM. Is there anyway I can combined .live() here in order to have jQuery watch for it when it is brought in via XHR?

** EDIT **

here's the actual code that's being executed. no javascript errors. It just does a full page submit instead of an XHR update.

```
 jQuery("[name='clip_form2']").live('submit', function(e) { 
      $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#form_quotes_highlights_part',

        beforeSerialize: function(form, options) {
          alert("In beforeSerialize...");
          if (validate_time_text_highlights()) {
            if ( $tabChanged ) {
              diff(form[0]);
              jQuery('form[name=clip_form2] input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val("<%= t('labels.please_wait') %>");
              return true;
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
          return false;
        },

        success: function() {
          jQuery('#form_quotes_highlights_part').fadeIn('slow');
        },

        complete: function() {
          jQuery("#wizard").expose().close();
        }
      });
      $tabChanged = false;

      add_change_listener("form[name=clip_form2]");

      Tabs.validateCancel( $( "button[name=Cancel]", "form[name=clip_form2]" ) );

      $("#clip_quote").NobleCount('#quote_count');
      $("#clip_quote2").NobleCount('#quote2_count');
      $("#clip_attribution").NobleCount('#attribution_count');

      if ( <%= is_defined?( @permitted_clip_read_only ) && @permitted_clip_read_only %> ) {
        jQuery( 'form[name=clip_form2] input' ).attr( "disabled", true );
        jQuery( 'form[name=clip_form2] textarea' ).attr( "disabled", true );
      } 
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
jQuery("[name='myform']").live('submit', function(e) {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(/* code here */);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

`ajaxSubmit()` is where the magic happens (where as `ajaxForm()` just binds a submit handler), here we're just listening for the `submit` event and calling `ajaxSubmit()` then.

Comment: Any reason for ajaxSubmit() instead of ajaxForm()?

Comment: @randombits - I tried to elaborate on this above,  you can see here that `ajaxForm()` does very littke: http://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L444 it's just a binding mechanism that calls `ajaxSubmit()` underneath.

Comment: Could you not use .delegate instead()?  May get performance benefit.

Comment: @RyanP13 - possibly, it depends if you know of a more local context to bind to, if nothing else you can change  `jQuery("[name='myform']").live('submit', function(e) {` to `jQuery("body").delegate('[name='myform']', 'submit', function(e) {`

Comment: @Nick - agreed it may be easier to stick with .live() if you don't know the context.  I have had my current app change so much that i reverted back to .live() to prevent any further refactoring.  A shame as .delegate() is just so cool!

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick either way, the form is being submitted with a full page reload.

Comment: No JavaScript errors at all. Just a full page load for the form submit. I've gone ahead and updated the question with the full code excerpt.

Comment: @randombits - Your selectors differ here, what does the `<form>` tag in the response actually look like?